# Queue images to upload at once when 5 are selected

Tags: javascript, php, queue

I have this program which uploads images in real-time but I want to queue up the images in memory and convert them in a batch when the queue size reaches 5 images, the image is then uploaded to a server. Any lead or help on how to do it.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
//echo '<script>console.log({$name})</script>';
//echo $name;
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

// Select file type
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Valid file extensions
$extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");

// Check extension
if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){

    //Insert record
   $query = "insert into images(name,name2) values('".$name."','$unique')";
   mysqli_query($con,$query);

   // Upload file
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_dir.$name);

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I have no idea where to start and I have searched the internet but it isn't helping much. Any lead on how to do it. @Darkonekt